# Get hours out of a datetime

Tags: php, datetime

Trying to get the hours in 24 hours format from a datetime and nothing works:

```
$date=date_create("now");
date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string('3 hours'));
$finalDate = date_format($date,"Y-m-d H:i:s");

// $finalDate is "2013-12-25 15:06:45"
```

Tried the following:

```
date('H', $finalDate)); // getting 02
date('G', $finalDate)); // getting 02
$finalDate->hours); // getting nothing
date_format($finalDate,"H")); // getting nothing
```

Read all posts in this site, nothing solved it for me...

Comment: It's wise to start using the newer PHP's DateTime object instead of the functions. This way you can easily fetch differences and details of a/multiple DateTime object(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and "object syntax":

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->modify('+3 hours');

    echo $date->format('H');
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

`$date` is already an DateTime object.

All you need to do is:

```
$hour = date_format($date, 'H');
```

or

```
$hour = $date->format('H');
```

PS: ***Object oriented style is recommended over Procedural style.***

Answer (score 1):

Please use the newer DateTime object. I also added the out commented variant of how to see the difference between two different DateTime objects.

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2013-12-15 12:00:00');
$date2 = new DateTime('2013-12-25 13:30:30');

//$interval  = $date1->diff($date2);
//$diff      = $interval->format('%d');
//echo $diff;

echo $date1->format('H');
```

You can use the PDO variant of `$date->add()` to write what you did a little cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$timeStr=strtotime($finalDate); 

echo date('H', $timeStr);
```